# How to capture cancelling of dragging?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have a drag-and-drop functionality in my application using DragDrop event and DoDragDrop method to start dragging. The question is: how can I capture cancelling dragging when Esc is pressed during the process of dragging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the QueryContinueDrag event is designed to do.  It is raised on the drag source when the user presses the Escape key, the e.EscapePressed property will be true.  Set e.Action = DragAction.Cancel to cancel the D+D.

Comment: I need to add here that QueryContinueDrag event is raised for both source and target controls, but it is the source control that cancels Drag-n-Drop operation when Escape is pressed by default. So, to capture the cancel event you need to create the hanler in the control that is the source of the Drag-n-Drop operation.